# How to stack arrays and compute inverse using Numba?

Tags: python, numba

I need to compute some vectors, stack them vertically in an array and finally calculate the inverse of the stacked vectors. I am able to do that using numpy but for better performance (and to assign it to a separate thread), I want to the calculations using Numba.

The code below works without the `@njit` decortor but takes ages with larges values of `nRows x ncols x nFrames`, such as 151 x 151 x 24.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit


@njit
def compute_inverse_numba():
    nRows = 15
    nCols = 15
    nFrames = 2
    result_list = []
    for frame in range(nFrames):
        for row in range(nRows):
            for col in range(nCols):        
                array_of_args = np.random.normal(3, 2.5, size=(10, 3)) #dummy array, DIFFERENT LENGHTS
                vectors_list = []
                for arg in array_of_args:
                    vec = np.zeros((4, 10), dtype=np.float64)

                    vec[0, 0] = arg[0]
                    vec[0, 1] = arg[1] 
                    vec[0, 2] = arg[2]
                    vec[0, 3] =  arg[0] * arg[2]
                    vec[0, 4] = arg[0] * arg[2]
                    vec[0, 5] = arg[1]
                    vec[0, 6] = arg[0]
                    vec[0, 7] = arg[1]
                    vec[0, 8] = arg[2]
                    vec[0, 9] = 2.0
                    
                    vec[1, 0] = arg[0]
                    vec[1, 3] = 2.0 * arg[1]
                    vec[1, 4] = arg[2]
                    vec[1, 6] = 1.0
                    
                    vec[2, 1] = arg[1]
                    vec[2, 3] =  arg[0]
                    vec[2, 5] = 2.0 * arg[2]
                    vec[2, 7] = 1.0
                    
                    vec[3, 2] =  arg[2]
                    vec[3, 4] =  arg[0]
                    vec[3, 5] = 3.0 * arg[1]
                    vec[3, 8] = 1.0

                    vectors_list.append(vec)
                
                # vertically stack the results
                vectors_list = np.vstack(vectors_list)
                
                # compute inverse matrix
                inv = np.linalg.pinv(vectors_list)
                result_list.append(inv)

    return result_list


###########----main()
compute_inverse_numba()

print()
```

**Problem:** With the `@njit` decorator, I keep getting an exception for the stacking-related step:

```
TypingError: No implementation of function Function(<function vstack at 0x0000028EFFBB8180>) found for signature:
 
vstack(list(array(float64, 2d, C))<iv=None>)
 
There are 2 candidate implementations:
   - Of which 2 did not match due to:
   Overload of function 'vstack': File: numba\np\arrayobj.py: Line 6005.
     With argument(s): '(list(array(float64, 2d, C))<iv=None>)':
    No match.
```

I tried different options but nothing really worked out.

Comment: @pho that vstack is unknown. The above example is MWE, which works without njit decorator and my question is, how can I achieve the same results using Numba.

Comment: I edited your question to include the error message. In the interest of making it easy for people to answer your question, you should always include the traceback of the error.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `vstack` at all in this case: Since you already know the size of the array that's going to be created out of `vectors_list`, pre-define it and then assign to the appropriate rows:

```
@njit
def compute_inverse_numba():
    ...
        ...
                vectors_list = np.zeros((40, 10), dtype=float)
                for i in range(10):
                    arg = array_of_args[i, :]
                    ...
                    ...
                    vectors_list[i*4:i*4+4, :] = vec
```

To generalize this, your `vectors_list` needs to have a shape of `(array_of_args.shape[0] * vec.shape[0], vec.shape[1])`, and the assignment will be to `vectors_list[i*vec.shape[0]:i*vec.shape[0]+vec.shape[0], :]`

Answer (score 0):

you can manually stack arrays in a way that's compatible with Numba

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit
def compute_inverse_numba():
nRows = 15
nCols = 15
nFrames = 2
result_list = []
for frame in range(nFrames):
    for row in range(nRows):
        for col in range(nCols):        
            array_of_args = np.random.normal(3, 2.5, size=(10, 3)) #dummy array
            vectors_list = []
            for arg in array_of_args:
                vec = np.zeros((4, 10), dtype=np.float64)

                # ... [Fill vec as before] ...

                vectors_list.append(vec)

            # Manually stack arrays
            total_rows = sum(v.shape[0] for v in vectors_list)
            stacked_array = np.empty((total_rows, 10), dtype=np.float64)
            row_start = 0
            for v in vectors_list:
                row_end = row_start + v.shape[0]
                stacked_array[row_start:row_end, :] = v
                row_start = row_end
            
            # compute inverse matrix
            inv = np.linalg.pinv(stacked_array)
            result_list.append(inv)

return result_list

 result = compute_inverse_numba()
 print(result)
```